# MVP pattern: mapping view to presenter

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, mvp

I am building a shopping site. I have a presenter for presenting
product list and a presenter for basket.
A view called productlist require to show List of products and also
contain logic to add product to basket.

So is it proper to use both the presenter class in the view
productlist? normally it is one-to-one mapping between presenter and
view. what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product list as well as the shopping basket can be seen as widgets that might be placed on various pages. Your code could quickly become quite messy if you'd have to implement the shopping cart's presenter logic on every page that puts it on display. The same goes for a login control and many other controls that should be displayed on many if not all pages.

Every widget can be implemented as a separate user control. Every user control is a view by itself and should have its own presenter. The page then is just a collection of one or more views, a mashup if you will.

Comment: its the addtobasket button on the productlist(view) page that is implementing basket presenter logic. How can it be use as seperate widget.

Comment: Make it a user control. If you don't know how, here's a good place to start: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/controls/article.php/c19489/

Comment: Can you give me name of some book or some good tutorial on good implementation of this Pattern

Comment: It's a common practice in asp.net webforms. Just google "user control tutorial asp.net" and go from there. Good luck!

Comment: Can different views(widget) use same presenter one at a time? is it valid mvp pattern. like a widget to addtobasket and another widget of basket details and deleting it.

Comment: how to pass messages between widgets